Question about proof of decomposition theorem of persistence modules
a very specific question from me today. I am reading the paper "Decomposition of Persistence Modules" by Botnan and Crawley-Boevey, which you can find here.
For notation: $M$ is a functor from some category $\mathcal{C}$ into the category of finite dimensional vector spaces over a field. $\theta$ is a natural transformation from $M$ to $M$. For all $x \in \mathcal{C}$, $\theta_x$ induces a decomposition of $M_x$ by Fitting's Lemma: $M_x = Ker(\theta_x^n) \oplus Im(\theta_x^n)$ for some large enough $n$.
In section 3, on page 6, the following is written: "if $\alpha : x \rightarrow y$ is a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$ then $M_{\alpha} \theta_x = \theta_y M_{\alpha}$. Moreover $M_{\alpha}$ sends $Im(\theta_x^n)$ to $Im(\theta_y^n)$ and $Ker(\theta_x^n)$ to $Ker(\theta_y^n)$."
The argument for this relies on being able to pick a parameter $n$ large enough to obtain decompositions of both $M_x$ and $M_y$ for it using Fitting's Lemma.
This is of course doable when we are only considering two elements in $\mathcal{C}$. But this needs to hold for any
morphism $\alpha : x \rightarrow z$ for all $z \in \mathcal{C}$, so we potentially need an $n$ large enough for the decomposition of
infinitely many $M_z$ at once.
How do we know that a finite $n$ satisfying this condition exists?

Why do you think you need to decompose infinitely many $M_z$ at once - what do you want to show?

Well, that's how the proof goes in the paper I cited. We have this persistence module $M$ and an endomorphism of it $\theta$, and out of this we build $M'$ and $M''$ two new persistence modules. The way $M''$ is defined, for instance, is that for all $z$, $M''_z = Ker(\theta_z^{n_z})$ for some $n_z$. Hence the need to have infinitely many decompositions at once. The specific parameter $n_z$ chosen depends on all other $n_y$ in the way that I described in the post. In particular it needs to be larger than some integer for each $y$, and i feel that could lead to it not existing.

If you write down carefully what you want to show, you'll see that the conditions are witnessed on a finite set of objects.  Keep in mind that Fitting's lemma implies not just a decomposition for some large enough $n$, but a decomposition that is stable for all sufficiently large $n$.

I see, thank you, I understand now. The fact that the decomposition is stable for all sufficiently large n means we can just pick whatever n we like for which the decomposition works at all.
An additional question, for my own curiosity: why do we use Fitting's lemma over the usual decomposition theorem that would give $M_x = Ker (\theta_x) \oplus Im (\theta_x)$?

Well, $\theta_x$ need not be bijective on $\operatorname{Im}(\theta_x)$, which is kind of the point.  Also, since you have been able to resolve your question, you should write an answer to move this question out of the unanswered queue.
